# ListSelectionListener not changing panel

Tags: java, swing, listselectionlistener

I want a ListSelectionListener event to change a JPanel. I know it is getting fired properly because the print statement is working, however the panel does not change at all.

```
DefaultListModel leftList = new DefaultListModel();
JList order = new JList(leftList);
order.addListSelectionListener(this);
JPanel configPanel = new JPanel();

public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
 if(e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
        int index = order.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println(leftList.getElementAt(index).toString());
        configPanel.removeAll();
        configPanel.repaint();
        configPanel.add(new JLabel("nice"));
        configPanel.repaint();
        }
    }
```

I threw in the second repaint simply because I was out of things to try, however it still did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add components to a visible GUI the basic logic is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Basically all components have a size of (0, 0) when they are created so there is nothing to paint. You need to invoke `revalidate()` so the layout manager can give the components a size and location on the panel.

Comment: Thank you this worked, so if i have this right the jlabel would have shown up when the listener was fired but since it was size(0,0) it was just not visible and that was the only problem right?